# Cron and virtualenv

Tags: python, django, cron, virtualenv

I am trying to run a Django management command from cron. I am using virtualenv to keep my project sandboxed.

I have seen examples here and elsewhere that show running management commands from within virtualenv's like:

```
0 3 * * * source /home/user/project/env/bin/activate && /home/user/project/manage.py command arg
```

However, even though syslog shows an entry when the task should have started, this task never actually runs (the log file for the script is empty). If I run the line manually from the shell, it works as expected.

The only way I can currently get the command to run via cron, is to break the commands up and put them in a dumb bash wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/sh
source /home/user/project/env/bin/activate
cd /home/user/project/
./manage.py command arg
```

EDIT:

ars came up with a working combination of commands:

```
0 3 * * * cd /home/user/project && /home/user/project/env/bin/python /home/user/project/manage.py command arg
```

At least in my case, invoking the activate script for the virtualenv did nothing. This works, so on with the show.

Comment: One difference that I see is that the script will run manage.py with /home/user/project as the current working directory.  Your cron command would be run with your home directory as the cwd.  Maybe the log file is there?

Comment: Actually the log path is defined absolutely, it's simply not created/appended to because the script is not running.

Comment: A quick and dirty solution to cron issues is to dump your environment (in which your command is inexplicably working) with `env` and `export` them all in a bash script wrapper you call from the crontab.

Answer (score 340, accepted):

You should be able to do this by using the `python` in your virtual environment:

```
/home/my/virtual/bin/python /home/my/project/manage.py command arg
```

EDIT: If your django project isn't in the PYTHONPATH, then you'll need to switch to the right directory:

```
cd /home/my/project && /home/my/virtual/bin/python ...
```

You can also try to log the failure from cron:

```
cd /home/my/project && /home/my/virtual/bin/python /home/my/project/manage.py > /tmp/cronlog.txt 2>&1
```

Another thing to try is to make the same change in your `manage.py` script at the very top:

```
#!/home/my/virtual/bin/python
```

Comment: That also does not work. Forgot to put that in my list of things that do not work. Yes, I can run that command manually in the shell but it does not work from cron.

Comment: Did you replace `~` with the full path?  (You probably did, just making sure ...)

Comment: Ah, you've come up with a working example!

I've tried about every combination and activating the virtualenv appears to have no effect whatsoever. I do set my PYTHONPATH in .bashrc but this apparently is not used by cron? Will update my question to highlight your answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'd forgotten that cron runs under a very minimal environment.  The general recommendation is to write bash scripts to set up whatever environment your job will need.  You could try sourcing the bash profile directly in cron, but this can lead to subtle bugs depending on what's in your profile (perhaps if you have a separate and minimal profile for such needs, it would be fine).

Comment: A good way to test is to execute /bin/sh, and then try to execute your command from there. At least you'll have the same environment setup as cron.

Comment: cron jobs may fail because your packages are not installed in your virtualenv. Make sure you are using your virtualenv's pip so installed packages can be reached with the first instruction of this solution. Maybe you will have to call the virtualenv's pip by using its absolute path when installing packages (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952797/pip-installing-in-global-site-packages-instead-of-virtualenv)

Comment: I also had to explicitly declare my settings since I have different ones for local and productions. `--settings=path.to.settings`

Comment: You can use `~` in crontab command statements in a user crontab. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287038/cron-and-virtualenv/69037846#69037846

Comment: What "command arg" mean here? Could you please share a full example?

Answer (score 140):

Running `source` from a cronfile won't work as cron uses `/bin/sh` as its default shell, which doesn't support `source`.  You need to set the SHELL environment variable to be `/bin/bash`:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
*/10 * * * * root source /path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate && /path/to/build/manage.py some_command > /dev/null
```

It's tricky to spot why this fails as `/var/log/syslog` doesn't log the error details.  Best to alias yourself to root so you get emailed with any cron errors.  Simply add yourself to `/etc/aliases` and run `sendmail -bi`.

More info here:
http://codeinthehole.com/archives/43-Running-django-cronjobs-within-a-virtualenv.html

the link above is changed to:
https://codeinthehole.com/tips/running-django-cronjobs-within-a-virtualenv/

Comment: Or '.' (dot command), which is supported by /bin/sh `. /path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate`

Comment: DavidWinterbottom, if that is your real name, you're my hero. I never knew that about sh vs bash and source files. You've shone a light into my little bash-scripting world dude. Thanks.

Comment: If you have a `postactivate` file, you should be doing `source /path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate && source /path/to/virtualenv/bin/postactivate`

Comment: Regarding adding yourself to `/etc/aliases` this is a good read: [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65013/understanding-etc-aliases-and-what-it-does](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65013/understanding-etc-aliases-and-what-it-does)

Comment: Thanks! For me, this works rather than the accepted answer by Gerald.

Comment: what is 'root' for? can anybody explain

Comment: @adnanmuttaleb, I assume you know the `root` user and its privileges (king of the kings). The first column after cronjob timing is the user to execute the cronjob.

Comment: Does not work for me. The virtualenv is ignored.

Answer (score 41):

I am sorry for that nth answer but I checked the answers and there is really simpler and neater.

**Long story short**

Use the python binary of your venv in your cron :

```
0 3 * * * /home/user/project/env/bin/python /home/user/project/manage.py
```

**Long story**

We activate the virtual environment when we want to set the current shell with the python config of that specific virtual environment(that is binaries and modules of that).
It is relevant to work with the current shell : execute multiple python commands on the current shell without the need to reference the full python path of the venv.
In the frame of a cron or even a bash, which value to activate the environment ?
Besides I read in some answers some references to `bash` rather than `sh` or still to define a wrapper to call the Python code. But why the hell should we bother with these ?

I repeat, just do it :

```
0 3 * * * /home/user/project/env/bin/python /home/user/project/manage.py
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) confirms that :

> You don’t specifically need to activate an environment; activation
> just prepends the virtual environment’s binary directory to your path,
> so that “python” invokes the virtual environment’s Python interpreter
> and you can run installed scripts without having to use their full
> path. However, all scripts installed in a virtual environment should
> be runnable without activating it, and run with the virtual
> environment’s Python automatically.

Comment: It seems like people will never mind about learning the docs for the technologies they work with! Thanks for letting decency still exist in this planet!

Comment: I am still wondering why that works. For me the venv python just points to my normal system python. But it will magically pick up all my venv modules. Why does this happen?

Comment: This is by far the best answer for using venv in Cron to this day! Who bothers to read the documentation, right?

Answer (score 34):

Don't look any further:

```
0 3 * * * /usr/bin/env bash -c 'cd /home/user/project && source /home/user/project/env/bin/activate && ./manage.py command arg' > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Generic approach:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/env bash -c 'YOUR_COMMAND_HERE' > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The beauty about this is you DO NOT need to change the `SHELL` variable for crontab from `sh` to `bash`

Comment: 'Don't look any further' is a bold statement. Particularly, when the following answer claims to know the 'only correct way': https://stackoverflow.com/a/22724628/6919635

Comment: `bash -c` is unnecessary. Just use `.` command instead of `source`. You won't need to change the SHELL variable in crontab, or wrap your command with `bash -c`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287038/cron-and-virtualenv/69037846#69037846

Comment: The whole point of bash -c is to avoid setting the SHELL environment in cron. If you are sure that your scripts won't behave differently in sh then you can go ahead, but if you have tested on bash, then they might behave differently in sh. To stay on the safe side, I would prefer sticking to using bash -c or whatever your default shell is.

Comment: Does not work for me. The venv is completly ignored

Comment: For it to work, your command should include the following `cd /home/user/project && source /home/user/project/env/bin/activate && ./manage.py command arg`

Answer (score 16):

The only correct way to run python cron jobs when using a virtualenv is to activate the environment and then execute the environment's python to run your code.

One way to do this is use virtualenv's `activate_this` in your python script, see: http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide.html#using-virtualenv-without-bin-python

Another solution is echoing the complete command including activating the environment and piping it into `/bin/bash`. Consider this for your `/etc/crontab`:

```
***** root echo 'source /env/bin/activate; python /your/script' | /bin/bash
```

Comment: I'm very curious as to whether there's consensus that this is in fact the only correct way.

Comment: This is probably the only correct way. But there are other ways that works.

Comment: This isn't "the only correct way." I've successfully executed a script in a virtualenv simply by pointing the cronjob to the virtualenv's python binary, such as '/home/user/folder/env/bin/python'. No need to activate the environment whatsoever.

Comment: If you use custom PYTHONPATH in virtual environment env/bin/python will not work for you. That's why using of env/bin/activate is better

Comment: it depends on how you set the PYTHONPATH and if you set it in a way that requires "activating" the venv, you're doing it wrong

Comment: It worked for me. I could not run using absolute PATH with venv. Thanks

Comment: You don't need to pipe the command to bash. Just use `.` command instead of `source`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287038/cron-and-virtualenv/69037846#69037846

Answer (score 10):

Rather than mucking around with virtualenv-specific shebangs, just prepend `PATH` onto the crontab.

From an activated virtualenv, run these three commands and python scripts should just work:

```
$ echo "PATH=$PATH" > myserver.cron
$ crontab -l >> myserver.cron
$ crontab myserver.cron
```

The crontab's first line should now look like this:

```
PATH=/home/me/virtualenv/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:  # [etc...]
```

Comment: Not a good solution. Every python tasks in the crontab would then run with the binary from the virtualenv. Making that binary a _pseudo-global_ python goes against the very purpose of virtualenv.

Answer (score 6):

This is a simple way that keeps the crontab command very similar to regular command (tested in Ubuntu 18.04). Some key notes to keep in mind:

- You can use the `.` command instead of `source`. (crontab uses `sh` by default, not `bash`, so it doesn't have `source`.)
- `~` and `$variables` are expanded in crontab commands. (It's only crontab environment statements that don't do variable expansion.)

Here are examples if you have a file `~/myproject/main.py`:

```
* * * * * cd ~/myproject && . .venv/bin/activate && python main.py > /tmp/out1 2>&1
```

You could also directly call the specific path of the `python` in the venv directory, then you don't need to call `activate`.

```
* * * * * ~/myproject/.venv/bin/python ~/myproject/main.py > /tmp/out2 2>&1
```

The downside of that is you would need to specify the project path twice, which makes maintenance trickier. To avoid that, you could use a shell variable so you only specify the project path once:

```
* * * * * project_dir=~/myproject ; $project_dir/.venv/bin/python $project_dir/main.py > /tmp/out3 2>&1
```

Comment: Thank you for your examples. I was in similar conundrum and your @wisbucky solution worked for me (except I had to source bin/activate)

'* * * * * cd /path/to/myproject && source bin/activate && python main.py'

Answer (score 4):

The best solution for me was to both

- use the python binary in the venv bin/ directory
- set the python path
  to include the venv modules directory.

`man python` mentions modifying the path in shell at `$PYTHONPATH` or in python with `sys.path`

Other answers mention ideas for doing this using the shell.  From python, adding the following lines to my script allows me to successfully run it directly from cron.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/path/to/venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages');
```

Here's how it looks in an interactive session --

```
Python 3.3.2+ (default, Feb 28 2014, 00:52:16) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import sys

>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python3.3', '/usr/lib/python3.3/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.3/lib-dynload']

>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'requests'   

>>> sys.path.insert(0,'/path/to/venv/modules/');

>>> import requests
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to add this because I spent some time solving the issue and did not find an answer here for combination of variables usage in cron and virtualenv. So maybe it'll help someone.

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DIR_SMTH="cd /smth"
VENV=". venv/bin/activate"
CMD="some_python_bin do_something"
# m h  dom mon dow   command
0 * * * * $DIR_SMTH && $VENV && $CMD -k2 some_target >> /tmp/crontest.log 2>&1
```

It did not work well when it was configured like

> DIR_SMTH="cd /smth && . venv/bin/activate"

Thanks [@davidwinterbottom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7031758/1300386), [@reed-sandberg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287038/cron-and-virtualenv#comment32136772_7031758) and [@mkb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3639466/1300386) for giving the right direction. The accepted answer actually works fine until your python need to run a script which have to run another python binary from venv/bin directory.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on python and using a Conda Virtual Environment where your python script contains the shebang *#!/usr/bin/env python* the following works:

```
* * * * * cd /home/user/project && /home/user/anaconda3/envs/envname/bin/python script.py 2>&1
```

Additionally, if you want to capture any outputs in your script (e.g. print, errors, etc) you can use the following:

```
* * * * * cd /home/user/project && /home/user/anaconda3/envs/envname/bin/python script.py >> /home/user/folder/script_name.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

> python script

```
from datetime import datetime                                                                                                                                                                
import boto   # check wheather its taking the virtualenv or not                                                                                                                                                                        
import sys                                                                                                                                                                                   
param1=sys.argv[1]     #Param                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
myFile = open('appendtxt.txt', 'a')                                                                                                                                                      
myFile.write('\nAccessed on ' + param1+str(datetime.now()))
```

> Cron command

```
 */1 * * * *  cd /Workspace/testcron/ && /Workspace/testcron/venvcron/bin/python3  /Workspace/testcron/testcronwithparam.py param
```

> In above command

- ***/1 * * * *** - Execute every one minte
- **cd /Workspace/testcron/** - Path of the python script
- **/Workspace/testcron/venvcron/bin/python3** - Virtualenv path
- **Workspace/testcron/testcronwithparam.py** - File path
- **param** - parameter

Answer (score 1):

I've added the following script as `manage.sh` inside my Django project, it sources the virtualenv and then runs the `manage.py` script with whatever arguments you pass to it. It makes it very easy in general to run commands inside the virtualenv (cron, systemd units, basically anywhere):

```sh
#! /bin/bash

# this is a convenience script that first sources the venv (assumed to be in
# ../venv) and then executes manage.py with whatever arguments you supply the
# script with. this is useful if you need to execute the manage.py from
# somewhere where the venv isn't sourced (e.g. system scripts)

# get the script's location
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"

# source venv <- UPDATE THE PATH HERE WITH YOUR VENV's PATH
source $DIR/../venv/bin/activate

# run manage.py script
$DIR/manage.py "$@"
```

Then in your cron entry you can just run:

```
0 3 * * * /home/user/project/manage.sh command arg
```

Just remember that you need to make the `manage.sh` script executable

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and spent a lot of time solving that.
None of the solutions here helped me, so I'm sharing what worked for me:

1. Open a new file "pick_name.sh" open it inside of your project directory.
2. Inside the "pick_name.sh" file, write and save the following lines:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
source /YOUR_VIRTUAL_ENV_PATH/bin/activate
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/PATH_TO_CUSTOM_MODULE_YOU_CREATED**OPTIONAL**"
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/PATH_TO_ANOTHER_CUSTOM_MODULE_YOU_CREATED**OPTIONAL**"
cd /PATH_TO_DIR_STORING_FILE_NAME.PY
python file_name.py
```

3. Go to /var/spool/cron/crontabs (or to where your cron management file sits) and open the 'root' file.
4. Add these lines to the root file which's inside the crontab folder:

```bash
# m h  dom mon dow   command
* * * * * /PATH_TO_DIR_WHERE_PICK_NAME.SH_SITS/pick_name.sh >> /YOUR_PROJECT_DIR/cron_output.txt 2>&1
```

**Notes:**

- This command (section 4.) will run the "pick_name.sh" file.
  In this example it runs every minute, so make sure you change it according to your needs.
  It writes all logs to a log file called "cron_ouput".
  No need to create the file before, it will be created automatically.
- Make sure to replace all paths (I wrote them in capital letters) to your paths.
- You can change file names, if so, make sure to change it in all appearances in my instructions to avoid errors.
- If you want to add another py file to run by cron, you need to add it to the *"pick_nam.sh"* file* not to the cron. Simply duplicate section 2. lines in the "pick_nam.sh" but without the "#!/bin/bash" part.
  Then, every time the cron will run "pick_name.sh" it will run all the files you specified inside of it.
- Make sure to restart cron after changes, it could have saved me a lot of debugging time, use this command:

```bash
systemctl restart cron
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the path of the Python installation in the venv but don't activate the environment.

```
* * * * * /HDD1/shritam_kumar/VENOM/venv/bin/python /HDD1/shritam_kumar/Projects/Voelkner-DE/schedule_product_BA.py
```

It's that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Since a cron executes in its own minimal `sh` environment, here's what I do to run Python scripts in a virtual environment:

```
* * * * * . ~/.bash_profile; . ~/path/to/venv/bin/activate; python ~/path/to/script.py
```

(Note: if `. ~/.bash_profile` doesn't work for you, then try `. ~/.bashrc` or `. ~/.profile` depending on how your server is set up.)

This loads your `bash` shell environment, then activates your Python virtual environment, essentially leaving you with the same setup you tested your scripts in.

No need to define environment variables in crontab and no need to modify your existing scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a MacOS user like me, you can check the crontab error message at /var/mail/{username} file. like this

```
tail /var/mail/{username}
```

If there is an "operation not permitted" error, maybe you have to add cron to the Full Disk Access apps (Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access apps/execs).

And click + button, go to /usr/sbin, double click the **cron** file.
then it will fix the "not permitted" error. [detailed steps](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378553/crontab-operation-not-permitted)

And this is my code：

```
0 19 * * * cd /Users/user/Desktop/Project && source /Users/user/Desktop/Project/venv/bin/activate && python command arg
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this worked for me (generic):

```
* * * * * cd /home/user/project && /home/user/project/.venv/bin/python /home/user/project/project.py  >> /home/user/project/project.log 2>&1
```

Note:

- creates a log file project.log in the project directory (troubleshooting)
- assumes .venv is already created
- assumes these entries also present in crontab file:

  SHELL=/bin/bash
  PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

Answer (score -1):

This is a solution that has worked well for me.

```
source /root/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && \
conda activate <your_env> && \
python <your_application> &
```

I am using miniconda with Conda version 4.7.12 on a Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

I am able to place the above inside a script and run it via crontab as well without any trouble.

Answer (score -1):

This will also work on crontab -e

```
* */5 * * * cd /home/project && sudo /home/project/venv/bin/python scripte.py
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this same issue:

I had written a custom django command to check for geodjango position coordinates inside of geodjango polygons and had trouble automating the task to run, however using this command with crontab worked for me:

```
* * * * * ./home/project/locations/locations.sh >> /var/log/locations.log 2>&1
```