# Why does crontab not run my Python program?

Tags: python-2.7, cron

I want to have a Python program run every minute using crontab, as seen in the picture.

However, it does not work. Why not?

I added an other job which prints the date and user and it works perfectly fine (I have checked it using `tail -f /tmp/crontest.text`).

My lines:

```
* * * * * /home/pi/Labb2.py

* * * * * echo "crontest $(date) $(whoami)" >> /tmp/crontest.txt
```

Comment: Does it work if you say `/usr/bin/python /home/pi/Labb2.py`? That is, place the full path of Python before the script. You can check it with `which python`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute python Script on Crontab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727935/execute-python-script-on-crontab)

Answer (score 0):

You are only specifying a file name, which will make nothing run.

You have 2 options:

1) Add a shebang at the top of your `.py` file:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

2) Explicitly call python on this file.

```
/usr/local/bin/python /home/pi/Labb2.py
```

(as a comment said, you can use `which python` to know the correct path)

As a side note, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommend to use all small caps for file names (`labb2.py` instead of `Labb2.py`)