# Running python script from crontab

Tags: python, cron

I've got a python file called `color.py` that if I run using `python color.py` will work on a file. I can run it okay from the terminal but it doesn't get called from crontab. I've used `chmod +x color.py` to try and make it executable.

The py file does start with

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

and the cron command is

```
*/1 * * * * /root/images/color.py
```

Comment: here are some hints: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727935/execute-python-script-on-crontab. I think you have to change /usr/bin/env to /usr/bin/python (use 'which python' to discover where your python is)

Comment: Have you tried to run it as `/root/images/color.py`?

Comment: @Rawing I can run it from images folder using python color.py

Comment: @SamuelM. That's not what I asked - can you run it as `/root/images/color.py`?

Comment: @anneb tried changing to /usr/bin/python and chmod a+x hasn't worked

Answer (score 1):

First check if following command works by running as user root (su or sudo):

```
/usr/bin/python /root/images/color.py
```

If that works, then edit crontab to:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python /root/images/color.py
```

How do you check if the cron job succeeds or not?

Comment: the command works and it deletes a file(s) that's how I know the task's done

Comment: do you reference the file to be deleted by its full path? Not delete 'myfile' but something like delete '/root/images/myfile' ?

Comment: using os.remove(filename) @anneb

Comment: is ' filename' full path or not? If it is 'myfile' it will only work if you explicitly change the working dir to the directory containing the file, if it is '/root/images/myfile' then that should be ok

Comment: I've edited to this been more than a minute but the file still is there, I know if I run python color.py it's going to colour the image make a new file and delete the old one.

Comment: the cron job normally runs in /root, to check manually if your python program is ok: first 'cd /root' then '/usr/bin/python /root/images/color.py' Does that work?

Comment: root@color:~# pwd
/root
root@color:~# /usr/bin/python /root/images/color.py
root@color:~#

Comment: It works but doesn't work on call, don't know what the issue might be.

Comment: put `*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python /root/images/color.py >> /var/log/color.log 2>&1` in your crontab and inspect /var/log/color.log for error messages

Comment: What is your username? Use "whoami", is it root or something else? When you test the python script, what is your directory? Use "pwd" to find out. The code in file color.py script does NOT use full path names, so it can only work if running in the correct directory. If the correct directory is the directory containing color.py, then add the following to python script: `abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)
os.chdir(dname)`

Comment: I've found out there's a script that crashes when it's running from cronjob only.