# Crontab Python Script Not Working

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, cron

I am running a python script on a Linux EC2 instance (the standard AMI) and I am having trouble executing a python script through the Crontab. I have another cron job already running and followed the same format. I think I'm missing something simple, but have had trouble identifying the cause. Here is what pops up when I run `crontab -e`

```
*/5 * * * * ~/scripts/aws-scripts-mon/mon-put-instance-data.pl --mem-used-incl-cache-buff --mem-util --disk-space-util --disk-path=/ --from-cron
*/1 * * * * ~/scripts/python cpu-util.py
```

The error I get in the logs is `/bin/sh: /root/scripts/python: No such file or directory`

I'm a little confused about this error message because the path from when I log in is ~/scripts, which has my Python script.

I also tried `*/1 * * * * ~/scripts python cpu-util.py` (which I thought made more sense), but [rearranged my code based on this other post to no avail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727935/execute-python-script-on-crontab).

Also, does it matter if I run these tasks from root or ec2-user? I just put the same scripts in both to be safe (sorry if this is two questions in one, but just curious about this...)

Any input would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your line you are looking for

> the python application inside your scripts folder

I guess this is not what you intended. Try this out:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python ~/scripts/cpu-util.py
```

I think this should work.

Also you can call it directly using ./ just putting inside your python script as the first line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Then you can run it like this

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/sh ~/scripts/cpu-util.py
```