# Execute function with interval

Tags: python, tornado

I'm setting up a tornado server. While this server is running i would like to make multiple asynchronous calls with an interval of 5 min. so when the server is running it should run a function every 5 min. I'm wondering what the best solution for this is? should i use something like [apscheduler](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler) or can it be done natively using tornado?

Comment: Cron could be an option? For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727935/execute-python-script-on-crontab

Answer (score 0):

It can be done natively with `PeriodicCallback`:

> Schedules the given callback to be called periodically.
>
> The callback is called every callback_time milliseconds. Note that the timeout is given in milliseconds, while most other time-related functions in Tornado use seconds.

You can read about it in the [docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html?highlight=periodiccallback#tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback).