# How to add a cron job from setup.py

Tags: python, cron, setup.py

How to add a cron job inside setup.py using the post installation commands (the cmdclass parameter).
The cron job will use the newly installed library to call a specific function from the library.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really vague, but you could do it if you wrote out a temp script somewhere to import said library and do whatever things you require, then write out a crontab to run a command such as:

```
py -<python version> <python script>
```

Some additional Python-specific info on cron jobs can be found [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727935/execute-python-script-on-crontab) which may be good to read, just in case.

To actually DO this, you'd add something like this to your setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install
class PostInstallCommand(install):
    def run(self):
        # PUT YOUR POST-INSTALL SCRIPT HERE or CALL A FUNCTION
        install.run(self)
```

You'd also need to add this to your setup() func:

```
setup(
    ...

    cmdclass={
        'install': PostInstallCommand,
    },

    ...
)
```

[Source for this info.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288711/post-install-script-with-python-setuptools)

Comment: But how do I add this to the post installation script in setup.py? This is my main issue

Comment: @Drxxd will fix, one second

Comment: @Drxxd done, sorry. I got distracted, so I pushed the incomplete answer.

Comment: I'm using the "PostInstallCommand" already. The main thing is how to add a cron job inside the runner (When the cron job will be a command that uses the newly installed library)

Comment: I'd need more info on the library and command to be able to tell you that (as i'd basically have to do it for you)