# How to set crontab for a Python and Selenium script at which the browser is to be opened at the time of script execution

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, web-scraping, cron

I have a Python script for [web scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) using Selenium. In that I want to execute the script in a period of time. For that, I want to know how to schedule using [crontab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Overview) on Ubuntu.

Crontab is not opening the browser and executing the Selenium automation, so is there another way to schedule the Python script?

Comment: why dont you simply do `crontab -e` and edit the file. This is one time task

Comment: Not executing would you help to do? @YugandharChaudhari

Comment: what is your time interval?

Comment: Please use the below link as this is already answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727935/execute-python-script-via-crontab

Comment: Please use the below link as this is already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727935/execute-python-script-via-crontab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run command

```
sudo  crontab -e
```

If you want to run your script every two hours,

```
0 */2 * * *  DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/python3.7 /home/monic/PycharmProjects/scrap.py
```

You can adjust the cron schedule from [here](https://crontab.guru/every-2-hours).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this tool](https://crontab.guru) to determine your cron expression.

Do

```
sudo  crontab -e
```

Choose the editor if asked *nano* is easier

Go to the bottom of the file use your cron expression interpretor and path to the python script like this

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/myuser/script.py
```

Above script will run every minute

**Explanation**

```
* * * * * is cron-expression 

/usr/bin/python is path to interpretor

/home/myuser/script.py is path to script
```

Comment: I did the same but not executing the script @Yugandhar Chaudhari

Comment: What is your time interval if it is too long then you should wait please post what you have done it is difficult to help without it

Comment: `19 13 05 11 02 /usr/bin/python /home/monic/PycharmProjects/scrap.py`

Comment: Your cron expression is wrong what is your time interval? Every day, every hour ? what is it?

Comment: It will only run At 13:19 on day-of-month 5 and on Tuesday in November.”

Comment: I set for the current time  to execute the script  1 19 PM (IST) NOV 15 Tuesday

Comment: yes at that time it  didn't execute @Yugandhar Chaudhari

Comment: What your script does it will run in background is it testable like getting an email?

Comment: As I said in question , webscraping using python and selenium and store extracted data to mysql

Comment: What timzone is set for crontab ?

Comment: India Standard Time

Comment: You should read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask