# Run python file daily on Google Compute Engine with Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-compute-engine, ubuntu-18.04

I need to run my python file once in every day on Google Compute Engine that Ubuntu 18.04 installed in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Crontab to run the script (here's the [crontab documentation](https://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference)) and make your .py file executable with "`chmod +x script.py`"

Similar topics were discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727935/execute-python-script-via-crontab) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/799023/how-to-set-up-a-cron-job-to-run-every-10-minutes).