# Python programm did not work with crontab but work alone

Tags: python-3.x, linux, cron, subprocess, popen

I am new to scheduling tasks with crontab. I am trying to open python script as if I open player and play some song. Programm work well alone, but with crontab its did not work.
my crontab task

```
*/5 * * * * cd /home/jack/projects/auto_stuff/18 && /usr/bin/python3.6 torrent_control.py
```

my code for open player and play song

```
with open('song.txt', 'a') as f:
    try:
        if player == 'play':
            subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/deadbeef', 'song.mp3'])
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc(file=f)
```

I know before subprocess code works right. I seen advice absolute path in "subprocess.Popen", but its already absolute or Im wrong?
I try to log my outputs to a file and script does not show any exceptions.
I change crontab task

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/python3.6 /home/jack/projects/auto_stuff/18/torrent_control.py
```

And I change script code:

```
with open('/home/jack/projects/auto_stuff/18/song.txt', 'a') as f:
    try:
        if player == 'play':
            subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/deadbeef', '/home/jack/projects/auto_stuff/18/song.mp3'])
            f.write('  Done.\n')
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc(file=f)
        print('Not done', file=f)
```

in song.txt output always 'Done.'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute Python script via crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727935/execute-python-script-via-crontab)

Comment: Where is song.mp3?

Comment: Try to log outputs from your python scripts to a file, to check if the script is executing or there is an error in your script. You can wrap your code in try...except to log the exception to the file.

Comment: @RamanSailopal song mp3 in same directory as .py file /home/jack/projects/auto_stuff/18

Comment: Try to not use cd. Instead use the full path to the py file in crontab and also reference the full path to the mp3 in your Python script.

Comment: @ace_racer I try to log my outputs to a file and script does not show any exceptions.

Comment: @dessand Try to log some informational messages to the log file at the beginning of the script to check if the python script was triggered by cron

Comment: @RamanSailopal I change crontab task, and again any exception, script work but 
the program does not open.