# How to run python script in cron

Tags: python, cron

I have a python script in the directory `/home/user/models/scripts`
When I create the cronjob

> `18 11 22 02 1  /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/models/scripts/test.py >> ~/models/scripts/cron.log 2>&1`
> It does not execute. How would i go about solving this?

**Python Script**

```
# set up logging
LOG_FILENAME = "/home/user/models/scripts/log_file.log"
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME, filemode='w', format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO, datefmt='%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S')

# Connect to the database
def database_config(user, password, database, port, host="localhost"):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(user=user, password=password, host=host, port=port, database=database)    
    return conn

...
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727935/execute-python-script-via-crontab) answer your question?

Comment: make sure u have `#!/usr/bin/python3` at the top of your code

Comment: @Anti_cse51 kindly note adding ``#!/usr/bin/python3`` did not resolve the issue.

Comment: did you give executable permission to your python code ? `chmod +x filename.py` ?

Comment: @Anti_cse51 yes

Comment: tried passing full path in `~/models/scripts/cron.log` ? also, did u try running the code manualy ?

Comment: When i run the ``/usr/bin/python3 /home/user/models/scripts/test.py >> ~/models/scripts/cron.log 2>&1`` the script runs smoothly but when i use cron it doesn't