# Django management command won't work in cron

Tags: python, django, cron

I am having problems scheduling a `manage.py celery call myapp.tasks.mytask` with my user crontab, in that when cron tries to run the job, it gets this in stderr (which gets mailed to me, as `/var/mail/kal`)

```
Unknown command: 'celery'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

The same command works completely from a regular bash login shell, but it won't work in crontab.

I am doing this on Debian wheezy:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.0 (wheezy)
Release:        7.0
Codename:       wheezy
```

I have read many similar questions on StackOverflow and tried many of the suggested solutions. None of them have worked for me so far. Here are the solutions I have tried so far:

First, I made sure to specify relevant environment variables in the crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

NOTE: these stay in place in all of the following solutions.

#### 1. Using full paths to the python executable and manage.py scripts

```
* * * * * /home/kal/.virtualenvs/foo_dev/bin/python /home/kal/foo/manage.py celery call myapp.tasks.mytask
```

#### 2. cd'ing into the project path first

```
* * * * * cd /home/kal/foo && /home/kal/.virtualenvs/foo_dev/bin/python ./manage.py celery call myapp.tasks.mytask
```

#### 3. Wrapping everything in a bash script

Content of ~/mytask.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source /home/kal/.virtualenvs/foo_dev/bin/activate;
cd /home/kal/foo;
./manage.py celery call myapp.tasks.mytask;
```

The crontab line:

```
* * * * * ~/mytask.sh
```

I even modified `myproj/settings.py` to output `sys.path` and `sys.executable` to stderr and compared the output between cron and the login shell, and they are exactly the same:

Output from cron job:

```
sys.executable:
    /home/kal/.virtualenvs/foo_dev/bin/python

Content of sys.path:
    /home/kal/foo
    /home/kal/.virtualenvs/foo_dev/src/bootstrap
    /home/kal/.virtualenvs/foo_dev/src/django-json-rpc
    /home/kal/.virtualenvs/foo_dev/lib/python2.7
    /home/kal/.virtualenvs/foo_dev/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2
    /home/kal/.virtualenvs/foo_dev/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
    /home/kal/.virtualenvs/foo_dev/lib/python2.7/lib-old
    /home/kal/.virtualenvs/foo_dev/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
    /usr/lib/python2.7
    /usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2
    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
    /home/kal/.virtualenvs/foo_dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    /home/kal/foo
```

Output from Bash login shell:

```
sys.executable:
    /home/kal/.virtualenvs/foo_dev/bin/python

Content of sys.path:
    /home/kal/foo
    /home/kal/.virtualenvs/foo_dev/src/bootstrap
    /home/kal/.virtualenvs/foo_dev/src/django-json-rpc
    /home/kal/.virtualenvs/foo_dev/lib/python2.7
    /home/kal/.virtualenvs/foo_dev/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2
    /home/kal/.virtualenvs/foo_dev/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
    /home/kal/.virtualenvs/foo_dev/lib/python2.7/lib-old
    /home/kal/.virtualenvs/foo_dev/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
    /usr/lib/python2.7
    /usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2
    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
    /home/kal/.virtualenvs/foo_dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    /home/kal/foo
```

I am completely baffled.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287038/cron-and-virtualenv?rq=1

Comment: @JohnMee I have tried that as well. Same results.

Comment: Do you have multiple settings files? Make sure you are using the correct one.

Comment: What user is the cron process running as? and does that user have permission to do all the things the script does?

Comment: @JohnMee Good question. Turns out there is no USER environment variable when the cron job runs. But why?? I'm already using the user crontab, not the root one. I have been doing `crontab -e`, not `sudo crontab -e`. And if I try `sudo crontab -e`, the content is clearly different.

Comment: @JohnMee So there is no `USER` environment variable, but there is `LOGNAME`, which correctly identifies as me (`kal`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem.

It is *very* **very** subtle.

The problem is two fold:

1. There is no `USER` environment variable in a cron job; only `LOGNAME`;
2. When `manage.py` is run *with a management command specified*, Django *quietly* fails over to blank settings if an exception is raised during the import of the settings module.

My settings module was trying to reference `os.environ['USER']`, which doesn't exist in cron's environment. So importing the settings module causes an exception to be raised, and Django quietly fails over to blank settings, which means blank `INSTALLED_APPS` and no `celery` command!

Answer (score 2):

Forget cron.
[Use the celerybeat_scheduler](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html).

Comment: I have actually tried using celerybeat, too. Using the official init.d script from the github repo, but I get the same problem (`Unknown command: 'celery'`).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `djcelery` is in `INSTALLED_APPS` in *settings.py* as seen at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery

```
INSTALLED_APPS += ("djcelery", )
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fabric to get this up and running. Your virtualenv is not activating perhaps but with a tool like fabric you issue a command

```
def reset_app_local(appname):
    run("source ~/env/bin/activate && python manage.py celery call myapp.tasks.mytask ",shell="/bin/bash")
```

And run the following if you run it on local server.

```
def reset_app_local(appname):
    local("source ~/env/bin/activate && python manage.py celery call myapp.tasks.mytask ",shell="/bin/bash")
```