# python manage.py crontab add, Unknow Command Error

Tags: python, django, django-cron

I am trying to configure django-crontab by following [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-crontab) article, I have done all the setting but when I am trying to add cron job by the following command, I am not able to add the job.

Django Version: 1.8.1
django-crontab: 0.7.1

Command Used:

> python manage.py crontab add

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
Unknown command: 'crontab'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

Comment: Did you miss  'django_crontab' in "INSTALLED_APPS ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django management command won't work in cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534923/django-management-command-wont-work-in-cron)

Comment: @MenglongLi no I didn't miss any thing, I follow all the steps that are mentioned in article..

Answer (score 1):

Check your pip packages and `INSTALLED_APPS`.  In my project I had typed `django_cron` instead of `django_crontab`.  `django_cron` is a different package than the instructions you linked to.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using a windows or linux? Because the above works only on linux.

Comment: is this comment or Answer?, fyi I am using Linux(ubuntu).