# A crontab script accessing Django models fails with ImportError

Tags: python, django, cron

I'm trying to use a crontab to execute a python script periodically. I followed the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287038/cron-and-virtualenv) to execute the command using virtualenv. Following is my crontab

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
HOME=/
MAILTO="myid@example.com"
* * * * * cd /home/jaskaran/edmhunters && /home/jaskaran/edmhunters/env/bin/python /home/jaskaran/edmhunters/scripts/db/songlist.py
```

I keep getting this ImportError

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/jaskaran/edmhunters/scripts/db/songlist.py", line 4, in <module>
   from hunt.models import DJ, Song
ImportError: No module named hunt.models
```

The script works fine when run from the shell. What am I missing?

Comment: Try putting those two lines into a shell script then run that, see if the error pop up while running from shell, then try again inside the cronjob.

Comment: @metatoaster I get the same error if run from a shell script. It seems `source env/bin/activate` and `/home/jaskaran/edmhunters/env/bin/python` don't work the same way.

Comment: Try going into some other directory and run the script via absolute path, with that virtualenv active.  I am suspecting that the `hunt.models` does not have an `.egg-link` of some sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django import errors are often misleading due to how Django loads its `INSTALLED_APPLICATIONS` and all implicit code what comes when Django tries to access its settings.

To work around, create a [Django management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) out of your script.

Then try this syntax if you need to run virtualenv'ed Django script or management command from shell script or cron:

```
 export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mymodule.settings ; /srv/django/myproject/venv/bin/python /srv/django/myproject/manage.py MyManagementCommand
```