# no module named error in python when running from crontab virtualenv

Tags: python, cron

I have a python script that runs fine when I am executing it from within a virtualenv but fails with the error "ImportError no module named oauthlib.oauth2..." I believe that the cron job needs to activate the virtual environment or that it is somehow related. I have tried many suggestions found on this site but without success. I am missing something and it's probably trivial.  The cron job runs as root and the code is under a different user. I am not sure how to solve this. Your help is truly appreciated.

Comment: You're right, you have to tell cron to start (if it isn't already) and use the virtual env.

Comment: I start the job and it runs the code but errors when it calls the module dependency "oauthlib.outh2"

Comment: What command are you telling cron to run?

Comment: * * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/myusername/projects/wl01/wl_cron.py >> /tmp/cron_output 2>&1

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the python that is in your `virtualenv` like so:

```
/srv/.virtual/wl/bin/python /home/myusername/projects/wl01/wl_cron.py >> /tmp/cron_output 2>&1
```

Sources and References:

[Cron and virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287038/cron-and-virtualenv)

Comment: my path for virtualenv is /srv/.virtual/wl/bin/python

Comment: my mistake hold up

Comment: I am receiving errors related to different parts of the code. But you have helped me get past the error related to my original question.