# On Mac, what should PYTHONPATH be set to in order to use "python manage.py run_command"?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, macos, pythonpath

I'm using Mac 10.13.6 with Python 3.7.  I use PyCharm for development.  Although I can run commands fine in the PyCharm management console, when I try and run the same commands in a terminal, I get errors complaining taht I don't have Django installed.  For instance

```
localhost:mainpage_project davea$ python manage.py runstats
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Perhaps I defined my PYTHONPATH incorrectly, but I set it to my Python executable

```
localhost:mainpage_project davea$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python

localhost:mainpage_project davea$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/usr/local/bin/python
```

What should be the value of PYTHONPATH?  I'm able to run the command fine within PyCharm, it's only in the terminal that things start throwing errors.

Comment: Do you use a python env when you code in pycharm or the modules are installed for your global python ? Did you try to run `pip install django` in your terminal ?

Comment: I think I do use a virtual environment, at least in my main project directory I have a "venv" sub-directory.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, then in this case you have 2 different instances of python the one in pycharm is using your venv with the django module installed, the one in your terminal is using system wide python without django installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pycharm you have Django installed (Check for an environment folder).

In order to use it in the terminal outside of pycharm either find the environment folder and activate it (source /bin/activate).

If a virtual environment does not exist, use this guide to create one: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

You could also (NOT RECOMMENDED!) install it system wide: 
    pip install django

Comment: Running "source /bin/activate" did allow me to run my command in a terminal.  So if I wanted to set up a cron to run my command periodically, would I always have to run the "source /bin/activate" first before any "python manage.py command" command?

Comment: yes! here is a reference for cron and virtualenvs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3287063/1067213

Answer (score 1):

In your terminal you could navigate to your pycharm project venv folder and do :

```
cd mainpage_project/venv
source bin/activate
```

Then you run your script:

```
(venv) localhost:mainpage_project davea$ python manage.py runstats
```

You could also install python system wide (not recommended) and then run your script:

```
pip install django
```

Then you run your script:

```
localhost:mainpage_project davea$ python manage.py runstats
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to where you are attempting to run from and set your PTYHONPATH to that directory:

```
export PYTHONPATH=.
```