# crontab not running shell script

Tags: python, bash, cron, raspberry-pi

Struggling to get *crontab* to execute a shell script on my Raspberry Pi. The script runs fine if executed with bash (it's executing a python script that runs in a virtual environment).

Here's what I've tried

```
crontab -e
```

```
* * * * * /home/pi/bash/myshell.sh
```

And the shell script...

```
#! /bin/bash
cd /home/pi/projects/scripts
source activate myEnv
python pyscript.py
source deactivate
```

This works fine...

```
bash /home/pi/bash/myshell.sh
```

I also tried editing the root cron tab file directly with `sudo nano /etc/crontab` but this also didn't work. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for everyone that took the time to answer. So the problem was not with crontab at all but was actually an issue with Python virtual environments. Using `source activate` was not working with crontab. The solution was to modify the shell script so that it directly uses the Python in the specified virtual environment. For example..

```
#! /bin/bash
cd /home/pi/scripts
/home/pi/berryconda3/envs/myEnv/bin/python pyscript.py
```

Also I had logging done within Python but because it crashed early in the script they were never written so I incorrectly assumed the crontab was not executing correctly. I have since discovered that it is a very good idea when working with *crontab* to log what's going on directly from cron like this...

```
* * * * * /home/pi/bash/myshell.sh >> /home/pi/logs/cronlog 2>&1
```

This way I could actually see what was going wrong (i.e. Python was throwing `ModuleNotFoundError`).

[There's a much better answer on this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287038/cron-and-virtualenv) that is worth looking at. I'll mark this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give executable permissions to the shell script:

```
chmod u+x /home/pi/bash/myshell.sh
```

The above sets permission for the file to be executed only by the owner or by the root user.

Comment: Thanks @Exadra. Should have mentioned I completed this step already. Does this look right? `ls -la`
`-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi  187 Oct  4 15:29 myshell.sh` Still not tunning.

Comment: Well everyone have permission to execute the bash script and that is not good from a security point, but that will not be the reason for not working from cron.

Comment: Try to use `sh` instead of `bash` in your shell script, like `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: Hey, just solved it. It was a problem with the Python virtual environment and not crontab at all, my bad. Removing the source activate and replacing the python line with `/home/pi/berryconda3/envs/myEnv/bin/python pyscript.py` worked. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Just add your own answer, and mark it as the accepted one. This will facilitate others to solve a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Set path at the beginning of your script - for example:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Comment: Thank you @Ut, still isn't running with the PATH line unfortunately.