# How to make a bash file to run a python script every 2 hours?

Tags: python, linux, cron, cron-task

I have in an virtualenvironment a python script that I wantt o run every 2 hours using a cronjob

This is my python script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time



PATH = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)



driver.get("http://bitcoin.works")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_link_text('LOGIN').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_id("login_form_btc_address").send_keys("MyEmail")
driver.find_element_by_id("login_form_password").send_keys("securePassword")
driver.find_element_by_id("login_button").click()
time.sleep(4)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("pushpad_deny_button").click()
time.sleep(7)
driver.find_element_by_id("free_play_form_button").click()
time.sleep(3)

driver.quit()
```

I also created a file in my folder named run.sh

that has following content

```
#!/bin/sh

python run.py
```

I than did

```
chmod a+x run.sh
```

After that i edited my the file under crontab -e

to this

```
0 */2 * * *  cd Documents/scraping && /bin/bash/ run.sh
```

why do I need the cd Documents/**scraping** && /bin/bash/ run.sh line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following command in the cronjob

```
0 */2 * * *   /bin/bash/ ~/Documents/scrapping/run.sh
```

I think this may help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your bash script has executable rights:

```
chmod +x run.sh
```

Type in `crontab -e`

and then type the following command:

```sh
0 */2 * * * cd /location/of/folder && /bin/bash run.sh
# Dont forget to leave a blank line at the end of the file
```

It is important to change the directory to the place where your file exists because the commands inside your `run.sh` are not absolute paths.

Comment: my python files isnt saved in /bin/bash- my python file is in Documents/scrapping/run.py

Comment: i thought i need to run the .sh file?

Comment: @charliebrown: I realized later that you have `run.py` AND `run.sh`. Try out the steps I have mentioned above :)

Comment: In crontab -e I put this line inside
0 */2 * * *  cd Documents/scrapping && /bin/bash/ run.sh
Is this enough to make it run- also is the content of my sh file correct?

Comment: You can verify if your `run.sh` executes properly or not by simply executing it from your terminal. Go on your terminal, change your directory to the location of `run.sh` and then type `./run.sh`, if this works then your cronjob should execute properly.

Comment: ok i ran run.sh but with my virtualenv activated and it works- do I only need to run ./run.sh once and than every 2 hours it should repeat the script

Comment: I also got this error when running ./run.sh ./run.sh: 4: ./run.sh: deactivate: not found- so if i just leave my virtualenvironment open i dont even need to specify in my sh file to deactivate the virtualenv?

Comment: Read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287038/cron-and-virtualenv it will explain you how to interact with virtualenv and cron correctly.

Comment: this answer doesnt make 0 sense

Comment: Urm, you can remove the deactivate part. It should work fine once you remove that :)

Comment: Please look at my question again- i edited to what im doing now

Comment: Now when running ./run.sh I get this error
./run.sh: 2: ./run.sh: source: not found
./run.sh: 3: cd: can't cd to Documents/scrapping
However the thing seems to work
What happens if i dactivate the virtualenv? Im sure its not working again cause it cant cd into the directory from bash script and - so i think the script will only work if the virtualenv stays activated?

Comment: the whole thing is now screwed up- cronjobs is such a garbage- if im in virtualenv and I run ./run.sh it works so why do i need to put this source Documents/scrapping/scrape/bin/activate into my bashfile if its not working?
Whats the bash file even for? how come there isnt a better way of running a simple file every 2 hours-

Comment: i removed everything from my bash file except python run.py and it works without errors- so i just leave the virtualenv running no?

Comment: Haha, yeah they are a pain sometimes... If your script is running properly without the virtual env then it shouldn't be a problem. It should work properly when cron tries to execute the job.

Comment: can you go inside `Documents/scrapping/scrape`, type pwd and show me the output?

Comment: /home/ether/Documents/scrapping/scrape   --- i need to run it in virtualenv

Comment: scrape is the name of my virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line to your crontab:

```
0 */2 * * *  python <path>/run.py
```

You can do this, among other ways, with:

```
crontab -e
```

Comment: why do i need to include the <path>? can i not just do 0 */2 * * *  python run.py

Comment: crontab is a system-level utility. It needs to know where your file is located.

Comment: but python Documents/scraping/run.py isnt working