# How to create a cron job in Django to run a script that scrapes data from a website and updates a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, cron

So I am currently implementing my very first Django-based web app. However, I figured that I only need Django to perform a backend cron job to scrape data from a website and then update existing data in a PostgreSQL database. Then I just use a React frontend to retrieve data from the database and visualize it on the webpage.

My issue now is that I don't know how to conceptually tackle this challenge. Currently, I have a model in my `models.py` file that successfully created my empty table in PostgreSQL:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class rainAreas(models.Model):
    Country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    HasRain= models.BooleanField()
    Since = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        app_label = "rain_areas"
```

I also filled the table manually with dummy data. Finally, I have a script in my `admin.py` file, which successfully creates the desired list of data scraped from a website. It looks like this:

```
my_data = [{"country": "Germany", "HasRain": True, "Since": "2020-08-11"}, {"country": "France",....
```

But now I am stuck. What is the next move to

1. make an SQL `UPDATE` on the table I created with the data I have in `admin.py`
2. transform this script to a cron job which should run every hour

Answer (score 1):

there are basically two options:

1. try to use [celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html)
2. write a [custom admin comand](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/)

Adding celery might add to much complexity.

if you go for the second option you have to ensure to use the correct python environment in your script/ in the cronjob check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3287063/13168118) answer

Updating the entries would be first retrieving and then saving the new value

```py
for d in my_data:
    rainArea = RainArea.objects.get(country=d['country'])
    rainArea.has_rain = d['HasRain']
    rainArea.since =  datetime.strptime(d['Since'], '%y-%m-%d')
    rainArea.save()
```

Please note that i slightly refactored the wording to better follow [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

- in python classes start uppercase
- django models are singular named and not plural (`RainArea`)
- attributes usually don't start with uppercase