# How do I restore my Python cron jobs after my Mac OS upgrade?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron, permissions, macos-big-sur

I recently upgraded to Mac Big Sur and have noticed my Python 3.8 cron jobs have stopped working.  Under my own account in a bash shell, I can run this without issues ...

```
davea$ cd /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/article_project; source ./venv/bin/activate; python3 manage.py check_duplicates
```

In my crontab, I had this set up, which used to work before the upgrade ...

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/article_project; source ./venv/bin/activate; python manage.py check_duplicates >> /Users/davea/logs/record2.txt 2>&1'
```

However, after the upgrade, I'm noticing my command is never run and I see this issue in my log file

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

These are the permissions/groups on my "manage.py" file ...

```
davea$ ls -al manage.py 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 davea staff 866 Apr 15  2019 manage.py
```

What else do I need to do to get my cron job to run again?

Comment: Try do delete your venv and create a new one

Comment: Have you checked the ` /var/mail/` to see if there are any other errors with the previous commands? Have you tried using `&&` instead of `;` to ensure that the python script will not run if the previous commands fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out with the new Mac OS there is an extra level of permissions that need to be enabled.  In System Preferences, under Security and Privacy, I clicked the Privacy tab, and then added "cron" to the "Full disk Access" list

[image]

then the cron jobs ran without the permissions error.

Comment: FYI for those visiting, `cron` can be located at `/usr/sbin/cron`.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case, python3 is considered as "any user" and with the `-rwxrwxr` permission it only have right to read the file, try to run `chmod 775 manage.py` in your folder to add permission to `manage.py` to be executed by "any user" (rigths should be set to `-rwxrwxr`), hope it can help.
EDIT: technically, read permission should be enough for python to run a file, but I can't see another reason why this error would appear, and I would be interested if you find one

Comment: Hi ,Yes I enabled +x (775) but still get the error.  I would prefer not to enable 777 perms.

Comment: It's just a supposition, but can the error come from the bash execution ? In this case, it might works by putting your commands in a ```.sh``` file, then running this file from cron (with a ```chmod 755``` on this one too).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a SIP or other mac-specific access permissions error, especially since it was right after an upgrade. Could be: https://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/

I've also had lots of problems working with venvs with cron, could be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7031758/13113166

It's also weird that the error comes from `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3` when i think it should come from your venv if it's activated correctly.