# How do I run python script that needs to be ran within virtualenv with cron?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron

I'm trying to run a Python script which needs to be executed with virtualenv activated with cron

Based on this [Cron and virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287038/cron-and-virtualenv) thread I've
come up with this:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
0 * * * * export FLASK_APP=/home/mark/off_web/project/__init__.py
1 * * * * export FLASK_ENV=development
*/10 * * * * root source /home/mark/off_web/venv/bin/activate && /usr/bin/python3 /home/mark/web_off/deletion.py
```

After editing I can see output `crontab: installing new crontab` but then I take a look if
the script has been executed and can see that it hasn't. Does `crontab: installing new crontab` also mean that it's triggering new execution ? `* * * *` means that it will be ran every day.

**Edit:**

edited crontab to look like:

`0 * * * * /home/mark/off_web/kick_off_deletion_script.sh`

kick_off_deletion_script:

```
#!/bin/sh

export FLASK_APP=/home/mark/off_web/project/__init__.py
export FLASK_ENV=development
. /home/mark/off_web/venv/bin/activate
/usr/bin/python3 deletion.py
echo "Executed"
```

after running the shell script I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'` despite it being installed.

Comment: Why not just make a shell script that will export your variables, activate your enviroment and call the python script, that way you just need one entyr on the cron to call the shell script

Comment: Yeah, I can definitely do that. In fact I've done it already. For some reason it throws an error saying Flask isn't installed even though it is. I'll add edit.

Comment: It's cause you execute the default python `/usr/bin/python3 deletion.py`. Change it to `python3 deletion.py` and you should be good

Comment: when you activate enviroment then use `which python3` to get path to python used in this enviroment - it should be something like `/home/mark/off_web/venv/bin/python3` - and you may try to use this path to run code without starting enviroment - so you may try to use it in cron.

Comment: `crontab: installing new crontab` means that it restarted `cron` with your new settings.

Comment: `* * * *` means that it will be ran every minut in every day. it gives 1440 runs every day (24h * 60min). Web service usually starts only once to run it all time. For example you could use `@reboot` in cron to start it when you start computer. On some Linux other method is to use service [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) which will check if your program is running and it will automatically restart it when it is crashed. Maybe you find more in [Full Stack Python](https://www.fullstackpython.com/)