# Load variables from a virtual env for a cron task on Azure web app server

Tags: django, azure, cron, azure-web-app-service, virtualenv

I have a python (Django) web app running on Azure App Service.

Despite everything I tried from other SO threads, I can't figure out how to have the environment variables accessed from my cron tasks. It may be caused by how Azure duplicates the `venv` into a weird `antenv`. More on that later.

What I **really** want is to use Django commands in cron, like `./manage.py some_command`. However, I quickly realized that the Django virtual env is not loaded properly in cron. So I decided to go step by step and see how to access the virtual env from cron.

## What I have tried

### Initial implementation

I am testing my setup using Azure App Service SSH console available at `https://{my-app-name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/webssh/host`.

#### Script

I created a script `/home/scripts/log-env.sh` to test the water:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
trace=/home/scripts/trace
path=$(...) # Some command that locates the venv directory
echo "src path: ${path}" > ${trace}  # I can see ${path} is set correctly
echo "MY_VAR before source: [${MY_VAR}]" >> ${trace}
source ${path}/antenv/bin/activate; echo "MY_VAR same command line as source: [${MY_VAR}]" >> ${trace}
echo "MY_VAR after source: [${MY_VAR}]" >> ${trace}
```

#### Output

When I run the script in the terminal, it shows that I don't even need to source the venv, as `$MY_VAR` is accessible before `source` is called:

```bash
# Content of trace file /home/scripts/trace when script runs in the terminal
src path: /tmp/8dbe5c185e85419
$MY_VAR before source: [expected_value]
$MY_VAR same command line as source: [expected_value]
$MY_VAR after source: [expected_value]
```

But when it runs from cron, `$MY_VAR` is not accessed, neither before nor after the venv is activated:

```bash
# Content of trace file /home/scripts/trace when script runs in cron
src path: /tmp/8dbe5c185e85419
$MY_VAR before source: []  # empty
$MY_VAR same command line as source: []  # empty
$MY_VAR after source: []  # empty
```

#### cron

I added the following entry to crontab:

```bash
> crontab -l
* * * * * bash /home/scripts/log-env.sh > /home/scripts/cron.log 2>&1
```

### Other attempts

I tried the following changes [that solved other questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3287063/1232651) but didn't work in my case:

#### Add `SHELL=/bin/bash` on top of the crontab:

```bash
> crontab -l
SHELL=/bin/bash
* * * * * bash /home/scripts/log-env.sh > /home/scripts/cron.log 2>&1
```

#### Source in cron

```bash
> crontab -l
* * * * * cd /tmp/8dbe5c185e85419 && source /tmp/8dbe5c185e85419/antenv/bin/activate && /home/scripts/log-env.sh > /home/scripts/cron.log 2>&1
```

## Azure `antenv/` vs usual `venv/`

For some reason, Azure server has a `antenv/` directory:

```bash
(antenv) root@23e4a05be277:/tmp/8dbe5c185e85419# ls -l *env
antenv:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 15 16:30 bin
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov 15 16:30 include
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov 15 16:30 lib
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  287 Nov 15 16:30 pyvenv.cfg

venv:
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 15 16:30 bin
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov 15 16:30 include
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov 15 16:30 lib
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov 15 16:30 lib64
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  282 Nov 15 16:30 pyvenv.cfg
```

It's the environment set by default. It is active when connecting to SSH, as the `(antenv)` prefix shows in the prompt:

```bash
(antenv) root@23e4a05be277:/tmp/8dbe5c185e85419
```

The `pyvenv.cfg` files look like as follows:

```bash
root@23e4a05be277:/tmp/8dbe5c185e85419# cat *env/*.cfg
# antenv/pyvenv.cfg
home = /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.11.6/bin
include-system-site-packages = true
version = 3.11.6
executable = /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.11.6/bin/python3.11
command = /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.11.6/bin/python3.11 -m venv --copies --system-site-packages /tmp/8dbe5c185e85419/antenv

# venv/pyvenv.cfg
home = /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.6/x64/bin
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.11.6
executable = /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.6/x64/bin/python3.11
command = /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.6/x64/bin/python -m venv /home/runner/work/jobalerts/jobalerts/venv
```

I tried the various changes with `antenv` as well as with `venv`. None worked.

Needless to say I am way out of my depth here. Any help with this mess is welcome.

Comment: For now, the least horrible workaround I found is this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/719903/how-to-set-my-django-apps-management-commands-as-c
I am not a huge fan of using `sleep` though.

Comment: You might consider using django-crontab which works quite well.

Comment: @Mess: I saw django-crontab during my search but it looked suspect, since the last update was more than 5 years ago, in 2018. But I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: @Mess, django-crontab doesn't work anymore than editing the crontab to call python commands from the virtualenv. I don't know what Azure did to their env, but no standard solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in a comment, for now, the least horrible workaround I found is this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/719903/how-to-set-my-django-apps-management-commands-as-c

I am not a huge fan of using sleep though. Since scheduling is a key part of my product, I'll look at alternatives to Azure and see if I could use cron there.